# Missing value from variable

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm trying to populate a `<select>` with `<option>`'s on a site with Classic ASP/VBScript. The values are read and taken from an SQL Server Database and the code for that looks similar to:

```
SET rows = dbc.execute(SQL)
    IF NOT rows.EOF THEN
        DO WHILE NOT rows.EOF
             %>  
                <option value="<%=rows("specialty")%>"><%=rows("specialty")%></option>
             <%    
             rows.moveNext
        LOOP
    ELSE    
END IF

rows.close
SET rows = NOTHING
```

The problem I have is that only one side of the `<%=rows("specialty")%>` seems to evaluate.

With `<option value="<%=rows("specialty")%>"><%=rows("specialty")%></option>` I get:

```
<option value="fromRow1"></option>
<option value="fromRow2"></option>
<option value="fromRow3"></option>
```

With `<option value="test"><%=rows("specialty")%></option>` I get:

```
<option value="test">fromRow1</option>
<option value="test">fromRow2</option>
<option value="test">fromRow3</option>
```

What should one do to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim a
Do while not rows.Eof
    a = rows.Collect("specialty")
    Response.Write("<option value=""" & Replace(a, """", "&quot;") & """>" & a & "</option>")
    rows.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: It's hidden method in ADODB.Recordset. It similar Field.Value property, but always return string type, and much faster than Field.Value. You can google in or see link http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18501

Comment: Never knew about `.Collect()` Very interesting and this seems to have fixed the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is the datatype of `specialty` ?

try this:

```
    DO WHILE NOT rows.EOF
    specialty = rows("specialty")
         %>  
            <option value="<%=specialty%>"><%=specialty%></option>
         <%    
         rows.moveNext
    LOOP
```

Comment: That's the most likely reason indeed, some field types get blank after first read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<option value='<%=rows("specialty")%>'><%=rows("specialty")%></option>
```

it might be getting confused with the doubles quotes.   But it has been a while since I've worked in Classic ASP