# select * in ASP page doesn't bring back some fields

Tags: sql, select, asp-classic

Just Weird.  I am using a Classic ASP page that is connected to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.  I am hosting the DB on my local machine.  I am using the query

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.screening WHERE ID = 21221;
```

I need display 2 fields using the following code:

```
  <input type="text" id="county_name" name="county_name" size="60" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("county_name").Value)%>">
  <input type="text" name="addresssdsd" id="addresszxas" size="49" value="<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("address").Value)%>">
```

The field address comes up blank.  County_name displays properly. However when I display the address field FIRST, both display normally.  I found that the address field is BEFORE the county_name field in the properties of the screening table.  Now if I set the address field AFTER the county_name field, it will display properly.  It's as if the  asp page will only display in the order they are set up.

When using the code `SELECT county_name,address FROM screening` (explicilately calling the fields, one by one),  this works properly no matter which field I select first.

ANY help would be appreciated.

Here are the connection strings:

```
connectstr="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=(local);UID=SA;PWD=pw111;DATABASE=Nceee"
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

Comment: Using the version where you list the fields is considered best practice and since that works I feel inclined to ask why you have a preference to go with `*`? Of course, It's perfectly valid to ask just to understand...

Comment: This is not the optimum, but you could work around this by pulling the values into a variable in the order they are selected and then setting them in the HTML controls from the variable instead of from the Recordset.Field.

Comment: We occasionally hit inconsistencies like this, although usually it's with more complex queries, not with simple `select * from table_name`. What usually helps is to play with the recordset type, i.e. the options at the end of the `rs.Open` statement.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but your code is vulnerable to XSS and other breakage. Always `Server.HTMLEncode()` any data you output to HTML. `value="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(Recordset1.Fields("county_name")))%>"`

Comment: Check: [Missing value from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16722688/1682881)

Comment: @Ron_Smith It happens when you have some `text,ntext` fields in your table. when you use `select *` clause you get all fields in rs ( including ntext ). All fields after `ntext` fiedld come blank. It is bug(feauture) of vbscript/ado. When this happen you should explicitly convert your `ntext` fields in query to `nvarchar(max)` ( or nvarchar(<N>))

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would recommend (this applies anywhere, not just to ASP):

1. As a matter of principle, never do `select *`. Spell out the fields you want to select. This eases the burden on the database server, makes way for query optimizations, helps when reading the ASP code and protects it from breaking all over when the database schema changes for some reason.

   ```
   SELECT address, county_name FROM dbo.screening WHERE ID = 21221;
   ```
2. Never build your SQL from concatenated strings. Use [ADODB.Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ADODB.Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675101(v=vs.85).aspx) objects. This protects you from SQL Injection and run-time errors due to unexpected parameter formats and helps speeding up queries that run in a loop.

   ```
   SELECT address, county_name FROM dbo.screening WHERE ID = ?;
   ```
3. Never output values to HTML unencoded. Use `Server.HTMLEncode()`. You could make a helper function that does it so you have to type do less typing:

   ```
   Function v(rs, name)
       On Error Resume Next
       v = Server.HTMLEncode(Nz(rs.Fields(name).Value))
       If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           v = Server.HTMLEncode(Err.Description)
       End If
   End Function

   Function Nz(val)
       If IsNull(val) Then Nz = "" Else Nz = val
   End Function
   ```

So...

```
<input type="text" id="county_name" name="county_name" size="60" value="<%=v(Recordset1, "county_name")%>">
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="49" value="<%=v(Recordset1, "address")%>">
```

Comment: why need to use `rs.Fields(name).Value`? why not just `rs(name)` ?

Comment: Same thing. Since VBScript is duck-typed I chose to spell it out so that from looking at the `v()` helper function it becomes immediately clear what `rs` is supposed to be, which might be helpful for maintenance. Equally I could have chosen to write `recordset` instead of `rs`. In any case, when writing something only once there is no real need for syntactic sugar.

Comment: spelling out fields is a pita in classic asp, because you don't have a micro orm, or orm you can recompile when your DDL changes...  I can understand why people want to use select * in asp, to do other wise is an atrocity to maintain.

Comment: ORM? Does no one write SQL anymore these days? Also, you're spelling out the field names every singe time you use them on the page, so writing them down in the query would not actually be a burden, would it. That, and your argument basically says "I deliberately write inefficient code because I'm lazy." That's wrong on pretty much every level.

Comment: @Tomalak the user you replied to (Ryios) probably never saw your comment because you didn't ping, you need to add a `@` character before the name to have a comment-reply and send notification to the other user. Anyway, I totally agree with you on all levels, and you're right - programmers these days will do anything to avoid writing actual code. They will look for packages and libraries and tools to do everything for them, just read this excellent blog post this morning: http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/

Comment: Don't worry, he saw it. StackOverflow's notification system is smart enough to figure this out.