# ntext record won't display if I display a datetime recordset ahead of it

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I've inherited a website and am moving it to a new host.
I've migrated my database to the new host and have started to tweak the code for my database queries.

I have a news story section and when I display the datetime record ahead of the ntext story record I get nothing for the story record.  All I do is remove the datetime and it shows up fine.  I don't get any errors except for not displaying the news story body.

Thanks for any help.  Connection stuff first in case that's somehow relevant, then a snippet near my problem area.

Updated the code to show more in case there is a problem with HTML but I don't think that is it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
<%
  ErrorMessage = ""
  StoryID = Request("StoryID")
%>
<%
Dim Connection
Dim ConnString
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL
ConnString = "Driver={SQL Server};SERVER=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;UID=gmax;PWD=Testing123;DATABASE=growmaxa_"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM NewsStory WHERE ID = " & StoryID

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Connection.Open ConnString
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection
%>
<title>News Story: <%= Recordset("Headline") %></title>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="float:left;
   width:500px;
   margin-top:10px;
   padding: 0px 10px 30px 0px;
   display:inline;
   border-top-right-radius: 20px;
   border-style:solid; 
   border-width: 1px 1px  0px 0px; 
   border-color: #0C0C89;">
<p style="font-size:xx-large;"><%=Recordset("Headline")%></p>
<%If Len(Recordset("Summary"))>0 Then response.write"<BR><H3>"&Recordset("Summary")&"</H3>"%> 
<p><%=Recordset("CreatedDate")%></p>
<p><%=Recordset("Story")%></p>
```

Comment: check this: [Missing value from variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735587/1682881)

Comment: You should show the full snipped. Where does the IF block end? There is no opening Tag for </B>?

Comment: Probably the record set before the date or any other field is outputting some html that is messing up the following code?

Comment: Please do not use snippet tags in your question unless you actually have a [runnable snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: snippet was the only one I could find that would actually display the code correctly...can you suggest an alternative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things that might help when it comes to classic ASP using ancient drivers.

1. Selecting the explicit fields, not "*" to select them all.
2. Storing the values to variables before displaying them.

Might sound weird, but over the years I've seen cases where it actually solved such problems.

So, using those tips, the code would look like this:

```
<%
SQL = "SELECT Headline, Summary, CreatedDate, Story FROM NewsStory WHERE ID = "
SQL = SQL + StoryID

Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Connection.Open ConnString
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

Dim strHeadline, strSummary, dtCreatedDate, strStory
strHeadline = Recordset("Headline")
strSummary = Recordset("Summary")
dtCreatedDate = Recordset("CreatedDate")
strStory = Recordset("Story")
Recordset.Close
%>

<p style="font-size:xx-large;"> 
<%=strHeadline%> </p>
<% If Len(strSummary)>0 Then response.write "<BR><H3>" & strSummary & "</H3>" %> 
<%=dtCreatedDate%></B><BR><BR>
<p><%=strStory  %></p>
```

Comment: @Jarret cheers, one just have to know Microsoft's weird sides... :-)